# Pass input to Bison from string

Tags: c++, c, file, d, bison

OK, so Bison/Yacc takes its input in `yyin` as `FILE*`.

**This is my current code** 
(it's in D, but the issue is not that D-related; a C solution would be easily convertible) :

```
auto file = File(filename, "r");

yyin = file.getFP();
yyparse();
```

How is it possible to feed it with a string (or a char buffer)?

Comment: Apparently you cannot use a string directly, since there's no equivalent for `std::istringstream` when `FILE*` is used. IMHO the simplest solution would be, to take the string, write it to a temporary file, and use this one as input.

Comment: "takes its input in yyin as FILE*." No it doesn't. It consumes tokens returned by yylex(). You write yylex() however you want. If you want yylex() generated by flex, and you want to feed a string to it, see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/780676/string-input-to-flex-lexer