# Implementing a function that parses a string using bison and flex

Tags: bison, flex-lexer, yacc, lex

I have implemented a parser and scanner using bison and flex. At first it read input from stdin and later I modified to read from a string.  There are several posts on stackoverflow on this topic. Specifically, the   at [flex manual](https://www.cs.virginia.edu/~cr4bd/flex-manual/Multiple-Input-Buffers.html#Multiple-Input-Buffers) describing the use of multiple buffers and the use of in-memory string rather than a file as input helped.

So, I got the parser/lexer to work for a single string as in:

```
%{
//Bunch of includes, typedefs, etc..
extern char * yytext;
void yyerror(char *);
int yylex();
typedef struct yy_buffer_state * YY_BUFFER_STATE;
extern int yyparse();
extern int yylex_destroy(void);
extern YY_BUFFER_STATE yy_scan_string(char * str);
extern void yy_delete_buffer(YY_BUFFER_STATE buffer);
...

%%
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  char *string = "abcd\n\0";
  YY_BUFFER_STATE buffer = yy_scan_buffer(string, sizeof(string));
  yyparse();

}
```

This was the simple part. The grammar/lex rules are a bit lengthy to reproduce here. 
I want to implement a function that will be called repeatedly with a string param. Since the grammar/lex rules can take care of the output, I can handle it. Problem is to have a mechanism to implement a classic function to which is passed a string to parse and analyse.  So, I tried this to test...

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int i=10;
  char *string;
  string = malloc(16);
  while (1) {

     sprintf(string, "someString to be parsed...%d\n\0", i++);
     YY_BUFFER_STATE buffer = yy_scan_buffer(string, sizeof(string));   
     yyparse();
     yylex_destroy();
     printf("%d\n", i); 

   }
}
```

It fails, after about 10000, with this error:

```
 fatal flex scanner internal error--end of buffer missed
```

I am not looking at any multi-threaded environment. It will be a single-threaded process with strings coming from a socket to be parsed. As a string arrives, I call a function to parse it. 
I am unable to find any reference on implementing such functionality with Bison and Flex.

I tried different approaches but with no luck. Any simple approach to handle this?

Comment: You probably have a buffer overrun somewhere in your code that normally is not an issue, but occasionally corrupts things such that you later get this error.  Try running with [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to see if it tells you anything useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string = malloc(16);
```

Is pretty stingy, considering that you are about to write:

```
sprintf(string, "someString to be parsed...%d\n\0", ++i);
```

which is at least 28 bytes if `i` is a single digit and reaches 32 bytes when `i` reaches 10000. (That's probably not a coincidence.)

Do yourself a favour and use `asprintf` if you can. If it's not available, it's easy enough to write it using `snprintf`, or you can just use`snprintf` with a much larger buffer. (No need to dynamically allocate in this case.)

Note that the `\0` at the end of the format string is totally pointless. I presume that your intention was to guarantee that there are two NUL terminators, as required by `yy_scan_buffer`, but the `\0` will not be copied into `sprintf`'s output since it's effect is to terminate the format string. (C strings are terminated by a NUL character, remember.)

Also note that `sizeof(string)` in `yy_scan_buffer(string, sizeof(string));` is `sizeof(char*)`, since `string` is a `char*`. That's most likely 8 these days, but it could be 4 if you're using a 32-bit environment. In any case, it has no relationship with the number of characters which `sprintf` wrote. You could use `strlen` to count the length of `string` but it would be more efficient to take advantage of the fact that `sprintf` returns the number of bytes it wrote.

And speaking of return values, you don't check the return value from `yy_scan_buffer`, which probably was trying to tell you about your error:

> If you fail to set up base in this manner (i.e., forget the final two YY_END_OF_BUFFER_CHAR bytes), then `yy_scan_buffer()` returns a NULL pointer instead of creating a new input buffer.

Comment: The key problem was  "Also note that sizeof(string) in yy_scan_buffer(string, sizeof(string)); is sizeof(char*), since string is a char*. "  Interestingly the reference was from this stackoverflow [link]( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/780676/string-input-to-flex-lexer) - sevko's answer - and I did not realize the obvious until you pointed out. Interestingly you have edited that answer but missed this point there -:)

Comment: @asinix: sevko's code is correct. `string` in that code is an array, not a pointer, and `sizeof` an array is the size of thearray, including null terminator. Also, initialising an array to a string containing `\0` does have the expected result; it's very different from your use of `sprintf`.

Comment: I didn't revise the answer in 2017 when I edited it. I rather laboriously edited several hundred answers (and some questions) which ended up with broken links to the flex manual after a commonly-referenced copy of the flex manual disappeared. I didn't have time to read all the answers I edited in any detail.

Comment: Agree! THanks for the clarification. I ought to read more carefully before commenting.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this is what you need but anyway this is what I wrote in Bison

```
int calc(char str[]) 
{
    YY_BUFFER_STATE buffer = yy_scan_string(str);
    yyparse();
    yy_delete_buffer(buffer);
    return 0;
}
```